# Confidence interval in normal Q-Q plot using `statsmodels`

Tags: python, statsmodels

I would like to do draw 95% confidence interval in `python` using `statsmodels`, but `qqplot()` doesn't have this option.

If it's not possible, math equation is also acceptable so that I can simply add it to the plot on my own.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(5, 10, 100)
fig = sm.ProbPlot(data, fit=True).qqplot()
plt.show()
```

There is an implementation in `R` that I found on the internet, but I am not familiar with `R`...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`pingouin`](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.qqplot.html) package has a function to create a qqplot with confidence interval lines. This would do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import pingouin as pg

data = np.random.normal(5, 10, 100)
ax = pg.qqplot(data, dist='norm', confidence=.95)
```

[image]